# Cannot find module 'typescript' from <Path> but tsc -v logs

Tags: macos, angular, typescript, node-modules, nrwl

I have a [project](https://github.com/morningharwood/platform) using [nrwl/nx](https://nrwl.io/nx) and I started the workspace(morningharwood) and an app(portfolio) on my home computer (windows).  On the move, I've now cloned the repo, `yarn install` the deps and tried to run on my mac. Unfortunately, when running `node_modules/.bin/ng serve --app=portfolio` I get an error that `Cannot find module 'typescript' from '/Users/m/projects'` locally and globally i have typescript install:

**Question:** Why cant my project find typescript; How can I run my project on my mac?

```
m@mac: ~/projects/ on feature/prerender [?]
$ tsc -v
Version 2.6.1

m@mac: ~/projects/morningharwood/platform on feature/prerender [?]
$ node_modules/.bin/ng serve --app=portfolio

Cannot find module 'typescript' from '/Users/m/projects'
Error: Cannot find module 'typescript' from '/Users/m/projects'
    at Function.module.exports [as sync] (/Users/m/projects/morningharwood/platform/node_modules/resolve/lib/sync.js:40:15)
    at Object.requireProjectModule (/Users/m/projects/morningharwood/platform/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/require-project-module.js:6:28)
    at Object.readTsconfig (/Users/m/projects/morningharwood/platform/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/read-tsconfig.js:6:48)
    at new NgCliWebpackConfig (/Users/mharwood/projects/morningharwood/platform/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-config.js:19:42)
    at Class.run (/Users/m/projects/morningharwood/platform/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/serve.js:71:29)
    at check_port_1.checkPort.then.port (/Users/m/projects/morningharwood/platform/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/serve.js:123:26)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
m@mac: ~/projects/morningharwood/platform on feature/prerender [?]
```

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
  "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
  "tsconfig-paths": "^2.3.0",
  "tslint": "~5.3.2",
  "typescript": "2.4.2", 
}
```

Comment: what is the location of package.json in your app? you should run ng serve from that location where node_modules folder is created.

Comment: have you tried using `ng serve --app=portfolio` instead of the full path

Comment: @Niladri yeah same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has be solved by issue 109
https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/109

Here's how you correct it:

> The issue is because the root property in .angular-cli.json is set to
>   "root": "apps\portfolio\src", if you change it to
>   apps/portfolio/src, it will work. I'll fix it.

Should be corrected in the future releases of nrwl.